# Django rollback not working after second objects.create fails to create a record

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

Here is the snippet code of the view:

```
@transaction.atomic()
def insert_in_sample_table(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            insert_obj = SampleTable1.objects.create(fld_id=2, fld_name='abc')
            raise Exception ("This is manual exception")
            insert_obj2 = SampleTable2.objects.create(fld_id=1, fld_name='xyz')
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(str(e))
```

There are two models:

1. `SampleTable1`
2. `SampleTable2`

I've manually raised an exception after first create and now I expect the changed done in first model(SampleTable1) must be undone.
But unfortunately I don't see the rollback

I've added   `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,` in DATABASE in settings.py file

I removed the

```
 @transaction.atomic()
```

and checked, it still does not rollback.

How to make the first database transaction rollback?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database used is Mysql

Comment: You will have to be more specific, because there are 2 types of MySQL databases, and the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#transactions-in-mysql) state that only 1 of those support transactions. You will need to figure out if you are using “InnoDB” (newer, has transactions) or “MyISAM” (older, does NOT support transactions).

Comment: I'm using InnoDB which actually supports rollback

Comment: I've edited my question. The problem with it was I did not add 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, in database in settings.py file. But now after adding the manual rollback in between two transactions I don't see a rollback

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the '@transaction.atomic' decorator, like this:

```
@transaction.atomic
def insert_in_sample_table(request):
    tra = transaction.savepoint()

    try:
         insert_obj = SampleTable1.objects.create(fld_id=2, fld_name='abc')
         insert_obj2 = SampleTable2.objects.create(fld_id=1, fld_name='xyz')

         transaction.savepoint_commit(tra)
         return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
    except IntegrityError:
         transaction.savepoint_rollback(tra)
         return HttpResponse("DB ERROR")
```

If you are using multiples databases, you should to specific the connection name and replace the line:

```
with transaction.atomic():
```

For this:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='connection_name'):
```

Comment: Hey there, I did add the save points but it is still not working.The first database transaction are not rolled back.

Comment: and if you add another exception line so that you capture the general error
`except Exception:`

`transaction.savepoint_rollback(tra)`
`return HttpResponse("GENERAL ERROR")`